# Remove records with same cross product values in AWK

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing, gawk, cross-product

When I do cross product of records in file.txt > file2.txt using command :

`join file1.txt{,} -j999 > file2.txt`

I get each record in file1.txt with all the records in file1.txt such as:

## sample dataset

```
r1
r2
r3
```

## I get

```
r1 r1
r1 r2
r1 r3
r2 r1
r2 r2
r2 r3
r3 r1
r3 r2
r3 r3
```

I dont want r1 r1, r2 r2, records and so on...

If its possible right while doing cross product, how do I get expected results? if not, How do I remove the records after processing join file1.txt{,} -j 999

I tried this with another awk command :

```
if($i!=$(i+12)){print $0;} and

if($1!=$13){print $0;}
```

Because I have serial number of each record 1,2,3,... 
I have file2.txt as :

```
c1  c13 --> column 1 and column 13
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   1
2   2
2   3
2   4
3   1
3   2
3   3
3   4
```

I simply compare serial numbers and if they are not equal print those records.
but I get undesired results, such as:

```
1  2
1  3
1  4
2  3
2  4
3  4
```

You can see it skips all the records before $1!=$13. so there are rows missing like:

```
2  1
3  1
3  2
```

it should only skip the records that are in pattern r1  r1, r2  r2,...

## Update

[image]

1st and 13th col is serial numbers.

Comment: Please update showing a [mcve] - and with text, not an image. Otherwise it is hard to work on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop twice through the file:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$0; next}
     BEGINFILE{lines=NR-FNR}
     {
       for (i=1;i<=lines;i++) {
           if (i!=FNR) print $0, a[i]
       }
     }' file file
```

This stores the data in an array `a[line_number]=value_on_that_line` when reading the first time. Then, when reading for the second time it just loops through the number of lines printing all the pairs except when the line number matches the index - that is, when they map  to the same line.

For your given file with r1, r2, r3 it returns:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$0; next} BEGINFILE{lines=NR-FNR} {for (i=1;i<=lines;i++) { if (i!=FNR) print $0, a[i]}}' f f
r1 r2
r1 r3
r2 r1
r2 r3
r3 r1
r3 r2
```

Comment: I am trying, but I have 4,000,000 records. and  I have 26 cols in total where r1 and r2 has 16 cols each And it is taking alot of time. is there an efficient way to remove than the one you provided? like just compare $i == $(i+12). if equal that is, in each record if a record has first 13 fields matching next 13 fields. remove the line? or print nothing so its removed?

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia: Are the column numbers fixed for both? like col 1 and 10 ?

Comment: @Inian please check the image

Comment: Are we sure, that the file contents have no repetitions?